# series of independent random variables of descending variance

Tags: sequences-and-series, probability-theory, random-variables

Let $X_{1},X_{2},\ldots$ be independent random variables such that $\mathbb{E}X_{n}=0$ for all $n$ and $\mathbb{E}X_{n}^{2}=n^{-2}$ for all $n$. Show that the series $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}X_{k}$ converges almost surely using Kolmogorov's three-series theorem.

Recall that the mentioned theorem says that a series $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}X_{k}$ of independent random variables converges almost surely if and only if the three following series converge for some real number $A>0$:

$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\mathbb{P}(|X_{k}|>A)<\infty$

$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\mathbb{E}X_{k}I\{|X_{k}|\leq A\}\ \text{converges}$

$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}Var(X_{k}I\{|X_{k}|\leq A\})<\infty$

Presumably for this problem any choice of $A$ should suffice, so define $Y_{k}=X_{k}I\{|X_{k}|\leq 1\}$. Then, because $Y_{k}^{2}\leq X_{k}^{2}$ and $Var(Y_{k})\leq\mathbb{E}Y_{k}^{2}$ we have that the series of the variances of the $Y_{k}$ converges. Likewise, using Markov's inequality we have that

$$\mathbb{P}(|X_{k}|>1)\leq\mathbb{E}X_{k}^{2}=n^{-2}$$

which gives us that the first series converges as well. Where I am stuck is the second series, the series of expectations of the $Y_{k}$'s. Using Lyapounov's inequality I can show that $\mathbb{E}Y_{k}\leq k^{-1}$, but I haven't been able to get a sharper bound.

How do you prove that the second series converges? Any hints would be appreciated.

Comment: Just use two series theorem.

Comment: I'm aware that the two series theorem proves the almost sure convergence of the series of $X_{k}$'s immediately, but the exercise was to show it using the three series theorem.

Comment: It converges if and only if $EX_k1_{\{|X_k|>1\}}$ converges, and $E|X_k|1_{\{|X_k|>1\}}\leq \sqrt{EX_k^2\cdot P(|X_k|>1)}\leq EX_k^2 = 1/n^2$.

Comment: I was just typing up the same thing as you posted your comment. I should have thought for just a little longer before asking my question. Thanks.

Comment: Yeah, I was trying to come up with some general argument, but nothing was coming to my mind, But I guess you could generalize it in this way.